# Tocloft package problem

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, captions, tocloft

My figure captions should be normal text, no bold no italic. But figure numbers  in List of figures should be bold. Also same for the List of Tables. Additionally for table of contents I need to bold only first depth titles and their page numbers. I need these:

Table of contents: https://ibb.co/jGJ1Ay
List of figures: https://ibb.co/mx3q3J
List of tables: https://ibb.co/eNz8qy

So obtain that lists I included these lines:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }
```

But I get following errors:

```
Argument of \@argdef has an extra }. \begin{preliminaries}
Illegal parameter number in definition of \@themark. \begin{preliminaries}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \begin{preliminaries}
Paragraph ended before \@vspacer was complete. \begin{preliminaries}
Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition. \begin{preliminaries}
```

Also this error:

```
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Argument of \@vspacer has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.233 \begin{preliminaries}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

Class and definitions file here:
http://www.filedropper.com/gsu12
http://www.filedropper.com/gsu12_1

How can I fix this problem ?

My tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneandhalf,chaparabic,ie,ms,eng,oneside,pntc]{gsufbe}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled,noline]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }

\author{JOHN DOE}
\title{Titleb2}
\trtitle{Titleb2}
\date{October 2014}
\supervisor[prof]{JOHN DOE}
\departmentofsupervisor{Industrial Engineering Department, ABC}
\committeememberi[assistprof]{JAMES DOE}
\affiliationi{Industrial Engineering Department, ABC}
\committeememberii[assistprof]{JESSICA DOE}
\affiliationii{Industrial Engineering Department, ABC}
\committeememberiii[assocprof]{RICK DOE}
\affiliationiii{Industrial Engineering Department, ABC}
\keywords{STEEVE}
\motscles{STEEVE}
\anahtarklm{STEEVE}

\abstract{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\resume{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\oz{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\acknowledgments{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.5cm}
% Preliminaries
\newlength\myindent
\setlength\myindent{6em}
\newcommand\bindent{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\myindent}
  \addtolength{\algorithmicindent}{\myindent}
}
\newcommand\eindent{\endgroup}
\begin{preliminaries}
\end{preliminaries}

\newtheorem{thm}{Definition}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{thm}}
\newtheorem{prp}{Proposition}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theprp}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{prp}}
\newenvironment{prf}{\noindent{\bf Proof}}{$\hfill \Box$ \vspace{10pt}}




\chapter{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\label{chap:intro}



\section{Lorem ipsum}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sit recusabo sententiae cu, ius iriure denique electram no. Justo clita dignissim sea ut, Table~\ref{table:summary22} sed aperiam fabulas id. Sea ea ludus gubergren posidonium, veri facete adipiscing pro cu, efficiendi reprehendunt pro an. His aliquam delenit an, pri commodo virtute ad. Ut usu tamquam insolens, essent eirmod ad vis As shown in.


\begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Results.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lllllrrrrrr}
        \toprule
        Test &    Vect. &     C & K-fold & Ngram &   Acc. &  Prec.  \\
        \midrule
        1 &    Aa &  0.01 &      2 &     3 &  0.361 &   0.13  \\
        2 &    Bb &  0.01 &      2 &     3 &  0.361 &   0.13  \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:summary22}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{svm}
    \caption{SVM.}
    \label{svm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Also a read only copy here:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/kvwdfwjknkwr

Comment: I'm not sure that your problem is caused by `tocloft`. What happens if yo don't use the package and its macros?

Comment: Manually I disabled and reenabled all packages. I found out that `tocloft` doesn't work when `algorithm2e` is active. When I don't use `algorithm2e`, `tocloft` works.